# Rails 4 - Writing a unit test for a method that contains config values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm just getting started with writing some unit tests in Rails and one of the problems I've ran into is how I should go about testing a method that contains configuration data.

The config.yml

```
drink_category_defaults:
1: #beer
  brand_id: 103 # 4.5%
  volume_id: 5 # Pint
  price: 300
2: #wine
  brand_id: 207 # 12%
  volume_id: 16 # Medium glass (175ml)
  price: 300
3: #cider
  brand_id: 304 # 4.5%
  volume_id: 12 # Pint
  price: 300
4: #spirits
  brand_id: 406 # 40%
  volume_id: 31 # Large single (35ml)
  price: 250
5: #alcopops
  brand_id: 502 # 4.5%
  volume_id: 52 # Standard bottle (275ml)
  price: 250
6: #champagne
  brand_id: 607 # 12%
  volume_id: 20 # Flute (150ml)
  price: 400
```

Method:

```
def self.new_with_defaults_for_category category_id
  drink = Drink.new
  category_defaults = APP_CONFIG['drink_category_defaults'][category_id.to_i]
  if category_defaults
    drink.drink_category_id = category_id
    drink.drink_brand_id = category_defaults['brand_id']
    drink.drink_volume_id = category_defaults['volume_id']
    drink.cost_per_drink = category_defaults['price']
  end
  drink
end
```

And the test I currently have:

```
# self.new_with_defaults_for_category
test "should return a new drink object with category defaults" do
  6.times do |i|
    i += 1
    drink = Drink.new_with_defaults_for_category(i)
    assert_instance_of(Drink, drink)
    assert drink.drink_category_id === i
    assert drink.drink_brand_id.present?
    assert drink.drink_volume_id.present?
    assert drink.cost_per_drink.present?
  end
end
```

I feel like I'm going about this in the wrong way. I probably shouldn't be using real config data, and that it should be mocked up for the test in some way. As well as that, just checking that the property is present isn't sufficient, and the test needs to be as specific as possible by checking the actual property values.

Would love some opinions on the best way to approach this, thanks a lot.

Comment: If your object relies on some sort of configuration data then it makes sense to actually test that and not mock the object under test. However I would question the approach with using a YAML file. I get using a bunch of XML files everywhere in Java and because writing Java sucks. However writing configuration in Ruby is easy and beautiful, loading a bunch a YAML not so much.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so would you suggest that for each drink_category I literally check to make sure that they are the same results that are contained within the config?

Eg:

    drink = Drink.new_with_defaults_for_category(1)
    assert_instance_of(Drink, drink)
    assert drink.drink_category_id === 1
    assert drink.drink_brand_id === 103
    assert drink.drink_volume_id === 5

Comment: Apologies for the terrible code formatting, didn't realise that didn't work within comments.